# How to enable 802.11n Wi-Fi?

Tags: networking, hardware-failure, wifi-configuration

I have a 150-Mbit capable router and a notebook with Atheros AR9485-EG wireless adapter.

The connection speed is always 54 Mbit/s. The router is set to b/g/n mode. If to set it into 11n-only mode the connection cannot be established at all. What should I do to enable 11n?

Comment: What type of encryption do you have on the wifi? Can other 802.11n devices connect when you set your router to 11n-only mode?

Comment: Please provide specifics on the router.  The only way it wouldn't be able to connect is the router was 5 Ghz and Atheros AR9485-EG only supported 2.4ghz or vice versa.  Which likely is the reason considering **MAC/baseband processor and 2.4 GHz radio**[product specification](http://www.qca.qualcomm.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/AR9485.pdf)

Comment: What is the speed of your land line?

Comment: @Ramhound the router is DIR-300NG B1E

Comment: @MariusMatutiae how on earth does it matter if the connection to the router is 54 Mbit/s?

Comment: @Canadian Luke I could not find any encryption settings in the router.

Comment: Because, if your land line has speed X, and you are trying to clock your wifi by transfering data from the WAN, you will be able to reach speed X at most, no matter what your wifi speed is. You can beat this speed and realize your full wifi speed only if you are transfering data inside your LAN, which you did not clearly specify.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae I do not clock the wifi, i see the speed in the network properties.

Comment: Then you should try clocking it, the network properties stated speeds are notoriously unreliable. Try shuffling around a large file in your LAN and time the operation. In your WAN, check www.speedtest.net

Comment: @Canadian Luke well I have just updated the router's firmware and got new encryption settings, set WPA/AES/PSK instead of WEP and got 90 Mbit/s! Still wondering how to get 150 though...

Comment: Wep encryption will limit the speed, which is why I asked. I'll write up more info when I get home

Comment: @Canadian Luke can u please tell how can I get 150 Mbit instead of 90?